# D-style Enum Syntax Support in cc-mode

Tags: emacs, d, cc-mode

I would like to extend `cc-mode` in Emacs to support D style enums as follow

```
enum EnumName: EnumType
{
    // enumerators...
}
```

The part `: EnumType` is the new part that needs to be supported.

Does anybody know how to solve this or which function to modify?

Emacs just got support for C++11 `enum class` syntax so maybe someone is up-to-date on this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an emacs user, but maybe the answer can be found in the d-mode you can find on github https://github.com/Emacs-D-Mode-Maintainers/Emacs-D-Mode On line 221 there seems to be a relevant function.

https://github.com/Emacs-D-Mode-Maintainers/Emacs-D-Mode/blob/master/d-mode.el#L221